# Pysimplegui keep animation running when executing two long functions sequentially

Tags: pysimplegui

I have two functions that will run for a long time inside my Pysimplegui application. I wonder how could I keep the animation running when executing these two functions? So that the user knows the application is still running.

My current code is like

```
func_1():
   something runs very long
return

func_2():
   something runs very long
return

while True:
   event, values = window.read()
   if event == "Start compute":
      window['-image-'].update_animation('progressing_1.gif')
      window.refresh()
      func_1()

      window['-image-'].update_animation('progressing_2.gif')
      window.refresh()
      func_2()
```

But what I found now is the gif is not moving when `fun_1()` is running. And I have to add a `window.refresh()` to change the `-image-` to a different gif file. I wonder what is the most elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo Code

```py
from time import sleep
import PySimpleGUI as sg


class Animation():

    def __init__(self, window, key):
        self.window = window
        self.key = key
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if self.running:
            self.window[self.key].update_animation(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF)
            self.window.TKroot.after(100, self.update)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.window[self.key].update(data="", size=(64, 64))

def f1():
    sleep(3)

def f2():
    sleep(5)

col1 = [[sg.Image(data="", size=(64, 64), key='F1')], [sg.Text('Function 1')]]
col2 = [[sg.Image(data="", size=(64, 64), key='F2')], [sg.Text('Function 2')]]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Start')],
    [sg.Column(col1), sg.Column(col2)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
running = False

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == "Start" and not running:
        running = True
        a1 = Animation(window, "F1")
        a1.start()
        window.perform_long_operation(f1, "F1 Done")
    elif event == "F1 Done":
        a1.stop()
        a2 = Animation(window, "F2")
        a2.start()
        window.perform_long_operation(f2, "F2 Done")
    elif event == "F2 Done":
        a2.stop()
        running = False

window.close()
```